# How remove unnecessary import from package eclipse for android

Tags: android

How remove unnecessary import from package eclipse for android.
When i add some method after removing it the import statements not getting remove.
Is there a way to remove from entire application...
Instead of removing one by one.

Comment: Please ask some meaningfull  question, for such a above question you can simply Google it and you will have lots of result

Comment: ok sorry i shall correct

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ctr + shift + o` for removing unnecessary import of your class.

It is not just for removing but also used for importing the class that is not yet imported to your class.

Answer (score 0):

The only way by which you import all defined packages that means

```
   CTRL+SHIFT+O
```